# How to construct a tensor weights whose certain elements are zero?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to construct a weight whose certain elements are zero and never change, and other elements are the variables.For example:

```
[[0,0,a,0],[0,0,b,0],[0,0,0,c],[0,0,0,d]]
```

This is a tf variable, and all zeros stay unchanged. Only a, b, c, d are tuned using gradient descent.

Are there anyone who knows how to define such a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor). It is highly optimised for operations where tensor consists of many zeros.

So, in your case, to initialise SparseTensor:

```
a,b,c,d = 10,20,30,40
sparse = tf.SparseTensor([[0,2], [1,2], [2,3], [3,3]], [a,b,c,d], [4,4])
```

Comment: However, what I need is a sparse tf.Variable. Now it seems this is a costant tensor?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001686/using-sparsetensor-as-a-trainable-variable/45779695) looks relevant. Also [this feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3907) on the tensorflow github.